# erro result.lenght ajax com wcf

Tags: ajax, for, wcf

O seguinte script funciona em parte:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function ConsUsuario(){
        var value = $("#codUser").val();

        $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "ServiceRestPub/ServiceUsuario.svc/ConsultarRegistroPorCodigo/" + value,
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (result) {
        alert(result.ConsultarRegistroPorCodigoResult.Nome);
          debugger;
          var tabela = $("#datagrid");
                            var rows = "";
                            tabela.find("tbody td").remove();
                            var jArrayObject = result;
                            for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
                                var obj = result[i];
                                alert(obj.Login);

                                rows += "<tr>";
                                rows += " <td>" + obj.Codigo + "</td>";
                                rows += " <td>" + obj.Login + "</td>";
                                rows += " <td>" + obj.Nome+ "</td>";
                                rows += " <td> <input type='checkbox' /> </td>";
                                rows += "</tr>";
                            }

                            // tabela.find("tbody").html(rows);
                tabela.html('<tbody>' + rows + '</tbody>');

            //console.info(result.d);
            }
        });
    }
 </script>
```

quando chego na linha for **(var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {** para pegar a quantidade de caracteres para varrer o objeto a mensagem é: Local
i
:
0
obj
:
undefined
result
:
Object e o processo para!
Como faço para varrer o objeto?

Comment: sou novo em javascript, mas creio que o result é: {"ConsultarRegistroPorCodigoResult":{"Codigo":2,"CodigoSetor":1,"Login":"ednilson1","Nome":"Ednilson","RegistroAtivo":true,"Senha":"123456","Tipo":"D"}} que é o retorno da consulta http://localhost/ServiceRestPub/ServiceUsuario.svc/ConsultarRegistroPorCodigo/2

Comment: E em qual propriedade desse obj tu quer trabalhar no for?

Comment: eu queria ler os campos Codigo, Login e nome o jogar eles na tabela para serem exibidos

Comment: Nesse contexto tu nem precisa do for, se result é um objeto simples.

Comment: poxa @Aline, falta de atenção minha, muito obrigado funcionou ok, não sei se cabe perguntar aqui ou deve ser outro post, mas se a tabela tivesse mais registros, como faria esse for, Lenght funcionar?

Comment: Adicionei a resposta. =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como seu objeto result não é uma lista, de acordo com seu comentário - que deveria ser adicionado ao post, remova o for e continue com o código exatamente como está:

```
var obj = result.ConsultarRegistroPorCodigoResult
rows += "<tr>";
rows += " <td>" + obj.Codigo + "</td>";
rows += " <td>" + obj.Login + "</td>";
rows += " <td>" + obj.Nome+ "</td>";
rows += " <td> <input type='checkbox' /> </td>";
rows += "</tr>";
```

Se result fosse uma lista de objetos, caberia seu laço de repetição:

```
$.each(result, function(indice, objeto){
   var obj = objeto.ConsultarRegistroPorCodigoResult
    rows += "<tr>";
    rows += " <td>" + obj.Codigo + "</td>";
    rows += " <td>" + obj.Login + "</td>";
    rows += " <td>" + obj.Nome+ "</td>";
    rows += " <td> <input type='checkbox' /> </td>";
    rows += "</tr>";
}
```

Comment: muito obrigado @Aline pela ajuda, resolveu meu problema!